# Difference between GLM and LM both with interaction term

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interaction, lm

We have mass spectrometry data (measurements of 100s of metabolites) from 4 samples. These were Non-treated, Treatment 1, Treatment 2, and Treatment 1 and 2 simultaneously.

The readout is intensities, which are a continuous data type. There are many metabolites, with relatively few replicates so as is typical of mass spec data, distribution is not reliably calculated.

We wanted to see what each treatment does allow as well as any interaction so we used the GLM function with two factors and their interaction. I want to check if this is actually a specific instance of the GLM that I have used (IE a linear model (LM)) as the default settings are:
Gaussian distribution and (Link = "Identity').

Specifically I would like to know if the following two models are equivalent:

```
mod1 <- glm(Intensity ~ factor(Treatment 1) + factor(Treatment 2) +
  factor(Treatment 1)*factor(Treatment 2))

mod2 <- lm(Intensity ~ factor(Treatment 1) + factor(Treatment 2) + 
  factor(Treatment 1)*factor(Treatment 2))
```

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. A lot of the software available for analysis of  mass spectrometry data as well as Prism include one-way ANOVAs but none allow for an interaction term. I heard that a GLM (using R) can allow for this but didn't realise that the LM function can do this as well. I came to the conclusion from looking at the options available in the documentation that the above "mod1" and "mod2"  are the same and just wanted to make sure I was right.

Comment: That's understandable, but if it's just a question about how the R code functions work, that's off topic here. If you have a question on the statistical issues involved, that would be on topic, but you should edit your Q to clarify that.

Comment: I can remove the question or is there a way of moving it to Stack overflow Otherwise Should I change the tags or question to "Are the GLM default settings  in R settings identical to LM?

Comment: This won't be on topic on SO, b/c it really isn't a programming question. I would just let it be for now; it will either be closed or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, run the code and you will observe the exact same results. So yes, they are the same. A linear model is just a special case of Generalized Linear Models (glm's) and it's the default in glm(). You can find all this in the help file of the functions though.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. The difference is that glm has other models you may use.

So, why do we have two ways of getting a linear model? The lm has been studied for longer time. So more analysis, statistics, etc can be found in a lm (i.e. R^2 is not common for all the glm)